# Having trouble creating set-based query to create table data instead of doing it procedurally

Tags: mysql, sql

Given table `settings` with unique key of `id`+`appId`

| id | appId | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | app1 | setting1 |
| 2 | app1 | setting2 |

I have created new entries and the table looks like so

| id | appId | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | app1 | setting1 |
| 2 | app1 | setting2 |
| 3 | app2 | setting1 |
| 4 | app2 | setting2 |

Then given table `user_settings` that connects settings to a user

| userId | settingsId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

I need to add all of the new settings that were added for `app2` to every user that currently has a setting for `app1`. The user should only get the settings that have matching `name`s though.

I don't know if that's clear so I'll say it this way as well: If the user has a setting of a given `name` for `app1` then it should get the setting with the same `name` for `app2`.

Is there a way to do this with set-based queries? Or do I have do this procedurally? I'm not great with much but basic SQL unfortunately.

So the `user_settings` table should end up being

| userId | settingsId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it:

```
select us.userid , s2.id
from user_settings us
join settings s1
   on s1.appid = 'app1'
   and us.settingsId = s1.id
join settings s2
 on s2.appid = 'app2'
 and s2.name = s1.name
```

you can use the same query to insert into your table.*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=032cc41463fb1350481cff5ed070c416)*

Comment: I accepted @Stu 's answer because it was first, but thank you for responding and showing a slightly different way as well.

Comment: @kamcknig you'r welcome , fyi I answered first

Comment: You are right, and for some reason I read the minutes backwards. I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

The `insert` statement you need can indeed be done in a single statement, one such way would be

```
insert into user_settings (userid, settingsid)
select u.userid, s2.Id
from user_settings u 
join settings s on s.id=u.settingsid
join settings s2 on s2.name=s.name
where s2.appid='app2' and s.appid='app1'
```